# How can I make a shape under which everything is transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I want to make an overlay for a video. I made two rectangular shapes in order to produce a gradient trim. Underneath is a picture. That part of the picture needs to be transparent so that I can place the video-feed under the overlay. How do I achieve that?

[image: sample]

The grey box is supposed to be there, for the chat. Just the bigger rectangle where the church is needs to be transparent.

For reference, I'm looking to a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Use the knockout group parameter in transparency panel

Comment: Thanks! I thik it doesn't work because the underlying image is not an object I can cut stuff out of. I probably must convert the image into an object somehow before that could work

Comment: knockout groups work with images aswell

Comment: To throw in my two cents; Illustrator is fine, but I would've used Photoshop or even After Effects to make that. But then again, this wouldn't be any easier to make in those applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **Clipping Mask** using a **Compound Shape** is *one way*. There are others.

- Draw a rectangle (or any shape) that defines the area you want transparent
- Draw a second rectangle (or any shape) which encompasses everything you want the "hole" to be in.
- Make certain the *smaller* rectangle is *on top* of the larger rectangle.
- Select both these rectangles and choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu.
- Select this new Compound Shape and select everything you want to "cut through"
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > make` from the menu.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have since achieved what I wanted following your steps. However, if I'm not drawing the shapes myself, if I'm "placing" a jpg-image as-is - it does not work. Would you be able to tell me the one (or two?) step that's missing.

Comment: The operations is the same. Imagine the pattern in the example above is a jpg... same steps.